# Importing multiple csv files with lappy

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

When i need to import multiple csv files I use:

```
Cluster <- lapply(dir(),read.csv)
```

Previously setting the working directoy of course, but somehow today it stopped working, and returning this error message:

> ```
>  Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>   no lines available in input
> ```

The only unusual thing i did was setting the Java directory manually so that way rJava can be loaded.

Any idea what happen?

Comment: To quote Gertrude Stein: "There's no there there." You need to provide more details about your setup. At the moment we can only guess about what you have done.

Comment: The error message says that you have an empty file in your current working directory.

Comment: use `getwd()` to see the current working directory. If it is not the intended one, then change the directory by `setwd(dirpath)`: The dirpath should contain the path to  the directory where you kept your csv files. Then type `dir()` to list the contents and try again to import it using read.table

Comment: @Psidom :L ooo i feel i little stupid rigth now, that was it!